# How do I allow WebView to consistently control login state without losing login credentials?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am creating my first android app and I thought I had finished it, but recently found out users were being logged out seemingly at random.

I'm using `WebView` to load a URL and the only time I manipulate the `WebView` is `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` within my `WebViewClient`in order to check for external links. Here's the gist of that:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String RequestUrl = request.getUrl().toString();
    if(request.getUrl().getHost() != null) {
         changePage(RequestUrl);
    }
    return true;
}

public void changePage(String UrlString){
    Uri RequestUri = Uri.parse(UrlString);

    if(RequestUri.getHost() != null) {
        if ((UrlString.contains("http://") || UrlString.contains("https://")) && RequestUri.getHost().equals(getString(R.string.app_domain))) {
            webview.loadUrl(UrlString);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, RequestUri);
            webview.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

This *shouldn't* be causing the problem.

I also use the website's login page to allow the user access with the purpose being to allow the web page to manage the login/logout state.

My problem is not that a user can't log in, or that they can't navigate the website through the app, but instead, after a while of navigating the `WebView`/website will lose the authentication provided by the initial login, effectively logging out the user. (All of this navigation I'm referring to is in-app/internal website links external works fine--I think).

Could this be due to the way I'm handling the links? Do I need to create some functionality to re-insert cookies on the request in order to create a consistent logged-in experience?

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
 WebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
   WebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data" + getPackageName() + "/cache");
   WebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
   WebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
   WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
```

Comment: The thing that actually solved my problem was including this configuration `CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);`. Please modify your answer to include this along with more detail and I will accept it.